# Oracle xmlexists in pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

in a regular query I can use the `xmlexists` function to look if a specific value is present in a `xmltype` column. But when I want to use it in a pl/sql block the script will not compile because of a syntax error (encountered the symbol "passing" when expecting one of the following...).

Simple script example:

```
DECLARE
  v_xml xmltype;
BEGIN
  for rec in (select xmltypecol from mytable where type='XXX')
  loop
    v_xml := rec.xmltypecol;
    if xmlexists('/test[node=(10,12)]' passing v_xml) then
      -- processing 
    end if;                                                          
  end loop;
END;
```

What is the right way to use `xmlexists` in a pl/sql block ?

Thanks!

Comment: `v_xml := rec.xml;` does not work, because you select only `xmltypecol`.

Comment: Indeed it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

Some Oracle `XML...` functions can be used only in SQL but not in PL/SQL - don't ask me why.

For example `v_xml := XMLELEMENT("number", 123);` is not possible, you have to run `SELECT XMLELEMENT("number", 123) INTO v_xml FROM dual;`

Try this one:

```
DECLARE
  v_xml xmltype;
  r INTEGER;
BEGIN
  for rec in (select xmltypecol from mytable where type='XXX')
  loop
    v_xml := rec.xmltypecol;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO r
    FROM dual
    WHERE xmlexists('/test[node=(10,12)]' passing v_xml);
    if r = 1 then
      -- processing 
    end if;                                                          
  end loop;
END;
```

Inspired by Boneist answer, why are you not doing

```
DECLARE
  v_xml xmltype;
BEGIN
  for rec in (select xmltypecol from mytable where type='XXX' AND xmlexists('/test[node=(10,12)]' passing xmltypecol)
  loop
    v_xml := rec.xmltypecol;
    -- processing 
  end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

XMLTYPE has its own methods, [one of which is existsnode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71960). That means you can avoid the context switching between PL/SQL and SQL that you'd have to do if you wrapped the call in a `select ... from dual` where by using `xmltype_variable.existsnode('<node>')`.

Your code would therefore look something like:

```
DECLARE
  v_xml xmltype;
BEGIN
  for rec in (select xmltypecol from mytable where type='XXX')
  loop
    v_xml := rec.xml;
    if v_xml.xmlexists('/test[node=(10,12)]') = 1 then
      -- processing 
    end if;                                                          
  end loop;
END;
```

However, what is stopping you from doing the check in the cursor? If you're only going to do the processing on the rows which meet your condition, wouldn't it be better to do the filtering in the query?

Also, if your processing involves DML, you could perhaps use XMLTABLE to produce something you could join directly to the DML statement(s) which would allow the processing to be done all at once rather than row-by-row, thus negating the need for cursor-for-loop processing at all?